# Let $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$, $x≠0$ and $f(0)=0$ then does there exist any function $g$ such that $g'=f$?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

My initial thought was in he direction let consider $\phi(x)=\int_0^{x} f(t) dt$. Now $\phi'(x)=f(x)$ if $f(t)$ is continuous at $x$. But here $f$ is not continuous so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Your $\phi$ is the only possible choice for answer.  And $\phi'(x) = f(x)$ for $x \ne 0$.  But, because of the reason you mention, you will have to find a different argument for $phi'(0) = 0$.  The result you quote says "if", not "if and only if", so there is still a chance it holds at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $g(x)=x^2\cos(1/x)$ $(x \not=0)$, $g(0)=0$ and
$h(x)=2x\cos(1/x)$ $(x \not=0)$, $h(0)=0$. Note that $g$ is differentiable
and $h$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Set
$$
F(x)=g(x)-\int_0^x h(t)dt 
$$
Now for $x \not=0$
$$
F'(x)= 2x\cos(1/x) + \sin(1/x) -  2x\cos(1/x) =  \sin(1/x),
$$
and
$$
F'(0)=g'(0)-h(0)=0.
$$
Thus $F$ is a primitive of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ has an antiderivative $g$ with the simple form,

$$g(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt = \int_0^x \sin \frac{1}{t} \, dt$$

As observed, the continuity of $f$ away from $0$  implies that $g'(x) = f(x)$ for $x \neq 0$. It remains to show that $g'(0) = f(0) = 0$.  By definition of the derivative, we have

$$g'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h \sin \frac{1}{t} \, dt$$

Without loss of generality we can consider $h > 0$, since for $h < 0$ we have

$$\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h \sin \frac{1}{t} \, dt= -\frac{1}{|h|}\int_0^{-|h|} \sin \frac{1}{t} \, dt = -\frac{1}{|h|}\int_0^{|h|} \sin \frac{1}{(-t)} \, d(-t) =  -\frac{1}{|h|}\int_0^{|h|} \sin \frac{1}{t} \, dt$$

With the change of variables $y = 1/t$ and using integration by parts, we get

$$\int_0^h \sin \frac{1}{t} \, dt = \int_{1/h}^\infty \frac{\sin y}{y^2} \, dy = \left. \frac{2 \cos y}{y^3}\right|_{1/h}^\infty - 2 \int_{1/h}^\infty\frac{\cos y}{y^3} \, dy = -2h^3\cos \frac{1}{h}-  2\int_{1/h}^\infty\frac{\cos y}{y^3} \, dy $$
Thus,

$$g'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\left(-2h^2 \cos \frac{1}{h}\right) - \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{2}{h}\int_{1/h}^\infty \frac{\cos y}{y^3} \, dy $$

The first limit on the RHS is clearly $0$ since $\left|\cos \frac{1}{h}\right| \leqslant 1$.  The second limit is also $0$ since,

$$\left|\frac{2}{h}\int_{1/h}^\infty \frac{\cos y}{y^3} \, dy  \right|\leqslant \frac{2}{h}\int_{1/h}^\infty \frac{|\cos y|}{y^3}\leqslant \frac{2}{h} \int_{1/h}^\infty \frac{dy}{y^3} = h \underset{h \to 0} \longrightarrow 0$$

Therefore, $g'(0) = 0 = f(0)$.